# Изменение "height" и "width" в разных разрешениях экрана

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование

Имеется такой скрипт :

```js
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#features').wowBook({height : 500, width  : 800, pageNumbers: 0, flipSound: 1,centeredWhenClosed : true
            ,hardcovers : true, controls : {
                next      : '#next',
                back      : '#back',
                first     : '#first',
                last      : '#last',
                slideShow : '#slideshow',
                flipSound : '#flipsound',
                fullscreen : '#fullscreen'
                
            }
        }).css({'display':'none', 'margin':'auto'}).fadeIn(1000);
            
    
        });
    </script>
```

Можно ли сделать так, что бы при определенных разрешениях экрана, менялись показатели "height" и "width"?

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот скрин, скопировал точно до символа вроде, но без обновления страницы не изменяются размеры

Comment: При изменении экрана или при начальных данных? Уточните и сейчас сделаем пример.

Comment: При изменении экрана

Comment: смотрите в ответе. тоже самое, только надо добавить функцию $(window).resize(function() {тут код});

Comment: Нужно до заменить функцию .ready или добавить ещё одну просто?

Comment: Добавить, так как изменения происходят всё равно после готовности страницы, а именно функции `ready`. Написал пример.

Comment: Уже гораздо лучше, но  размеры меняются только после обновления страницы

Comment: Вы не правы. Меняется при изменении экрана. Протестировано. Значит Вы не корректно скопировали. Который раз...

Comment: Ниже добавил скриншот, своего кода

Comment: Вы в него не добавили функцию `resize`. Смотрите внимательнее ответ, а если точнее, то вторую его часть.

Comment: А да все верно, но  в таком случае скрипт перестает вообще работать, но в любом случае,  уже лучше чем было.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var width = document.documentElement.clientWidth; // получаем ширину окна браузера пользователя
        var wowBookwidth = "";
        var wowBookрheight = "";
        if (width >= "1280"){ // Добавляем проверку на ширину, в зависимости от которой будем менять переменную ширины wowBook
            wowBookwidth = "800"; // Указываете свою ширину (это для примера)
            wowBookрheight = "500"; // Указываете свою высоту (это для примера)
        } else if (width >= "800" && width <= "1024"){
            wowBookwidth = "700"; // Указываете свою ширину (это для примера)
            wowBookрheight = "400"; // Указываете свою высоту (это для примера)
        } else if (width <= "800"){
            wowBookwidth = "600"; // Указываете свою ширину (это для примера)
            wowBookрheight = "300"; // Указываете свою высоту (это для примера)
        }
        console.log(width);
        $('#features').wowBook({height : wowBookрheight, width  : wowBookwidth, pageNumbers: 0, flipSound: 1,centeredWhenClosed : true
            ,hardcovers : true, controls : {
                next      : '#next',
                back      : '#back',
                first     : '#first',
                last      : '#last',
                slideShow : '#slideshow',
                flipSound : '#flipsound',
                fullscreen : '#fullscreen'

            }
        }).css({'display':'none', 'margin':'auto'}).fadeIn(1000);


    });
```

Если надо при изменении размера экрана, то добавьте функцию `$(window).resize(function() {...});`

Пример:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $(window).resize(function() {
        var width = document.documentElement.clientWidth; // получаем ширину окна браузера пользователя
        var wowBookwidth = "";
        var wowBookрheight = "";
        if (width >= "1280"){ // Добавляем проверку на ширину, в зависимости от которой будем менять переменную ширины wowBook
            wowBookwidth = "800"; // Указываете свою ширину (это для примера)
            wowBookрheight = "500"; // Указываете свою высоту (это для примера)
        } else if (width >= "800" && width <= "1024"){
            wowBookwidth = "700"; // Указываете свою ширину (это для примера)
            wowBookрheight = "400"; // Указываете свою высоту (это для примера)
        } else if (width <= "800"){
            wowBookwidth = "600"; // Указываете свою ширину (это для примера)
            wowBookрheight = "300"; // Указываете свою высоту (это для примера)
        }
        $('#features').wowBook({height : wowBookрheight, width  : wowBookwidth, pageNumbers: 0, flipSound: 1,centeredWhenClosed : true
            ,hardcovers : true, controls : {
                next      : '#next',
                back      : '#back',
                first     : '#first',
                last      : '#last',
                slideShow : '#slideshow',
                flipSound : '#flipsound',
                fullscreen : '#fullscreen'

            }
        }).css({'display':'none', 'margin':'auto'}).fadeIn(1000);
        });
    });
```